# Is it possible to disable blueprint in sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Is it possible to disable blueprint on certain controllers in sails?

I've created a controller and I would like to make it only accessible using the custom route I provided in the routes.js but when I do like controller/action I can still see the page.

In the controller I defined `_config: {blueprints: {action: false, rest: false, shortcuts: false }}`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there's an error in the docs.  You no longer need the interior `blueprints` object for your per-route controller config.  So in your controller, just do:

```
_config: { actions: false, rest: false, shortcuts: false }
```

and it should work fine.  Sorry about that!

-- Edit --

The above is valid for v0.10.x only.  For v0.9.x, you'll still need to define your per-controller config using `_config.blueprints`.

Comment: I still need `blueprint` object in sails 0.9.16, what version are you referring to?

Comment: Right, the above was for v0.10.x only, which I knew the OP was using.  Updated answer to clarify.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in v0.10 for the controller.js config file. Any reason why?