# How disable blueprints actions in single controller ? (Sails 0.12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Of course, we can disable blueprints actions globally with this following config:
(in config/blueprints.js)

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
 actions: false
};
```

But, I want to do this in single controller.

I use the last SailsJS version (v0.12.1) and in older versions, I know that we could do this:

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
   actions: false     // config blueprints actions just for this controller
  },
  index: function (request, response) {
    return response.view('homepage');
  }
};
```

All my research on the internet on this subject have given me that answer,
(As here: [Is it possible to disable blueprint in sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206264/is-it-possible-to-disable-blueprint-in-sails))
... Unfortunately it does not work on this version of sailsJS.

Someone would know how to do?

I don't want to disable actions and rest in blueprints globally because I use them all over my project.

PS: Thank you for the time you take to read my question and sorry for my english, it's not my language :)
Happy coding all!

Comment: ` _config: {
    rest: false,
  },` this work for me on 0.12.2

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
But, I tried again, and no change.

I have added in my controller config.
So I have (in my route.js config): 
`'get /': 'Homecontroller.index',`

And in my HomeController:
_config: { rest: false, actions: false },
`index: function (req, res) {
res.view('home'); 
}`

My home is accessible at:
 `baseurl/ `
but also at:
 `baseurl/home`
...so, the (blueprints) actions mode is always activated.

Comment: not working in 0.11.5 either

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sails v0.12.3 and it is not working either. I managed to workaround that and block the action through overriding the route:

```
'/home': {response: 'notFound'}
```